# how to get unfiltered objects given main array and filtered array?

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I created multiple checkbox filters in my app so user can filter the data based on different properties. 
here is a summary of what I did: I have an array of objects attached to $scope in my controller:

```
$scope.objects = response.data;
```

I am filtering this array based on some criteria in my controller:

```
var filteredObjects = $scope.objects;   
for(var i in filterType){
   filteredObjects = filterData(filteredObjects, filterType[i].selected, filterType[i].filterProp);
   }
```

and finally I assign to scope:

```
$scope.filteredObjects = filteredObjects;
```

now I want to pass the unfiltered objects to the filterData function so I can keep all filtered objects if user selects multiple checkboxes.
So given the $scope.objects and filteredObjects how can I make it? I was trying to do it using filterFilter but I don't know how to pass the filteredObjects to that function. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the unfiltered object by **filtering out** the filtered objects

```
$scope.unfilteredObjects = $scope.objects.filter(function(obj){
  return $scope.filteredObjects.indexOf(obj) === -1;
})
```